# Where is my composer global config information stored in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, composer-php

I added a wrong github token to my global composer configuration and cannot remove it again.

I did

```
composer config --global --auth github-oauth.github.com myWrongTokenDamn
```

Now I cannot overwrite it by executing it again with the correct token and I don't know where this information is stored to remove it manually.

The command to show where it is stored just gives me the error, that I am using the wrong token. Thanks I know that....

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and installed composer following [these instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and then moving the binary to `/usr/bin/composer`.

Reinstalling didn't help either, so the information clearly is not stored at /usr/bin/composer

Comment: It should be in `~/.composer/auth.json`.

Comment: That folder doesn't exist and neither therefore the file.
That was, where I was looking, too at first

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Weird solution:

I noticed that the behaviour did only occur, when I was within my current project, which had of course a composer.json file

What I did then I moved to my home directory and executed the the command again this time with the correct token:

```
composer config --global --auth github-oauth.github.com myCorrectLongToken
```

And the error message is gone.

While I am happy about the fix, it would be good if someone could explain what happened in the background.

Now

```
$ composer config --list
```

gives me the list of all settings including [home]

```
[home] /home/myUser/.config/composer
```

where everything is stored.

Comment: strange how `composer config --global` had to be run from home directory for this to work

Comment: @Ian: Imagine you have a $HOME/composer.json , the $COMPOSER_HOME is different to $HOME, that's perhaps all.