# Using external variables in the composer.json file when running the global composer command

Tags: composer-php

I would like to load private projects into a larger project. The multiple private repositories belong to different GitHub users and organizations. Therefore, I need to use at least 2 tokens. I found a solution for this, but it requires storing the tokens in the `composer.json` file.

**A direct use of tokens in the composer.json file**

```json
{
  "require": {
    "organization-name/repository-1": "^1.2",
    "organization-name/repository-2": "^1.2",
    "username/repository-3": "^1.2"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_token-first@github.com/organization-name/repository-1.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_token-first@github.com/organization-name/repository-2.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_token-second@github.com/username/repository-3.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I don't want to expose the tokens when uploading the project to the web server. **How can I replace the tokens with variables and declare these variables when running the global `composer` command?** (for example, when run `composer install` or `composer update`)

**Declaring external variables** (Just an illustration of what I would like to achieve)

```json
{
  "firstToken": "token-first",
  "secondToken": "token-second",
}
```

```json
{
  "require": {
    "organization-name/repository-1": "^1.2",
    "organization-name/repository-2": "^1.2",
    "username/repository-3": "^1.2"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_${firstToken}@github.com/organization-name/repository-1.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_${firstToken}@github.com/organization-name/repository-2.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_${secondToken}@github.com/username/repository-3.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not supported by composer.

You can write something else that spits out a new composer.json based on a template, extrapolating the contents from variables... but then it would no longer be a "composer" issue, composer would simply see the resulting JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Since GitHub does not allow pulling multiple accounts' repositories with one token, and [Composer can only handle one token per domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77773554/15167500), we need to find a solution where we can manage all our private repositories under a single token.

#### Alternative solution (Packagist)

> TBH that's a special use case due to poor repository construction which I am not so keen on supporting in composer. **[Private Packagist](https://packagist.com/) does support this though, as you can add the same repo as a third party mirror multiple times**, configuring each with a different set of credentials, and mirroring a different set of packages from each. So I'd suggest you maybe have a look at using that, or try and get your vendors to use it as a paid package repository, which is also something we offer and we then handle credentials correctly for customers.
>
> Duplicate of [#8724](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8724) BTW if you want to read more about this.
>
> Seldaek's comment: [composer/composer #10483](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/10483#issuecomment-1029105773) - GitHub

Answer (score -1):

**In short, it's not possible.** As a priority, my goal is to write the tokens (sensitive data) used in the file to a separate file, so I focused on solving this. This way I can avoid my own tokens going to the cloud.

**Only one token** can be associated (with github-oauth property) with github.com (not suitable in my case as I need to use multiple tokens). If you are using a single token, a **simple solution is to manage the tokens in the `auth.json` file**.

When using multiple tokens, there is no way to explicitly declare them (with github-oauth too). **For multiple tokens**, repositories must be specified individually, and each repository's URL must contain the appropriate token. This repository property **can also be placed in a separate file, globally in the composer `config.json` file**.

## Results

The original problem was that I wanted to access private repositories stored in various organizations and owned by different users within a large collaborative project. It is not feasible to create clones of the repositories, I want to use the original repositories in any case.

Composer provides an option to specify a GitHub OAuth token. However, the drawback is that only one token can be assigned to a domain. More details about this limitation are [discussed in the found issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/11204). There are [no plans to change this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/11204#issuecomment-1333754020) in the future.

If you **only want to keep one token** private in your `composer.json` file, you don't need to read any further. Just create an `auth.json` file and place [your single GitHub OAuth token for the github.com domain](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#manual-github-oauth) in it.

**local composer.json**

```json
{
  "require": {
    "organization-name/repository-1": "^1.2",
    "organization-name/repository-2": "^1.2"

    // In my case, I can no longer load the third repository because it doesn't belong to the token used for it.
    // "username/repository-3": "^1.2"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/organization-name/repository-1.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/organization-name/repository-2.git"
    }

    /*
    In my case, I can no longer load the third repository because it doesn't belong to the token used for it.
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/username/repository-3.git"
    }
    */
  ]
}
```

**local auth.json**

```json
{
  "github-oauth": {
    "github.com": "github_pat_token-first"
  }
}
```

So, my only option is to use what is referred to as "[inline HTTP authentication](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#inline-http-basic)" in the mentioned `composer.json`. This means that for each repository listed in the "repositories" section, I need to provide my token (even if repeated). This works as intended. However, having the tokens in the `composer.json` file, which is part of the project, means that it is committed to the shared GitHub repository. And here lies the problem: I don't want to expose my tokens.

As [@yivi pointed out, it is indeed not possible to use an external JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77769729/15167500) alongside `composer.json` where I could declare these repositories on my local development machine and exclude them from upload with `.gitignore`. I need to explore some other method.

The solution was to use the global `config.json`. It's basic, and I'm not entirely happy with it, but it's a workable solution.

I simply moved the access information for the three repositories mentioned in the question from the local `composer.json` to the global `config.json` file. This way, when running Composer, it read the global `config.json` and found the three private repositories with various inline tokens. Moreover, I could confidently upload the local `composer.json` to the cloud, knowing that it doesn't contain any tokens.

**local composer.json**

```json
{
  "require": {
    "organization-name/repository-1": "^1.2",
    "organization-name/repository-2": "^1.2",
    "username/repository-3": "^1.2"
  }
}
```

**global config.json**

```json
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_token-first@github.com/organization-name/repository-1.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_token-first@github.com/organization-name/repository-2.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github_pat_token-second@github.com/username/repository-3.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is no issue when running in GitHub Actions, as GitHub Actions already has the necessary permissions to access the three repositories. Therefore, running the tests based on the `composer.json` works seamlessly.

**Note to followers of the solution:**
Following this solution, the only challenge lies in uploading to my own web server. Since I would need to provide the tokens there as well during the installation of Composer.

#### In summary

Declaration in an external file that differs from the current project's `composer.json` is only possible in the global `config.json`.

Note: Authentication credentials can also be declared in a local [`auth.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#authentication-in-auth-json-per-project) file (in this case, however, only one token can be assigned to one domain, which is not a suitable solution for the question).

#### More information

###### Settings in a separate file

- [Information from `config.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#config) - Composer Docs
- [Where is composer global `config.json`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823178/where-is-my-composer-global-config-information-stored-in-ubuntu)

###### Authentication data in a separate file

- [Authentication in auth.json per project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#authentication-in-auth-json-per-project) - Composer Docs
- [Global authentication credentials](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#global-authentication-credentials) - Composer Docs
- [Defining a single token is possible in a separate file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md#manual-github-oauth) - Composer Docs